# JENKINS SVN Connectivity: E175002: timed out waiting for server

Tags: jenkins, svn, continuous-integration, visualsvn-server, request-timed-out

We are using SVN as our SCM tool and Jenkins as our CI tool. The first SVN checkout from Jenkins was successful. But the subsequent checkouts are failing with timed-out error.

The desired output is successful checkout and build.

```
18:04:53 ERROR: Failed to check out https://svnserver/svn/T11_2293_Digitalbanking/DevOps/EKYC-UTF8/ekycupdate
18:04:53 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
18:04:53 svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/T11_2293_Digitalbanking/DevOps/EKYC-UTF8/ekycupdate'
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:702)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:113)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1035)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:164)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:480)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:833)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:133)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:176)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:134)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1041)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1017)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:990)
18:04:53    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1042)
18:04:53    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:937)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:864)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
18:04:53    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
18:04:53 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
18:04:53    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
18:04:53    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
18:04:53    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
18:04:53    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
18:04:53    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
18:04:53    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
18:04:53    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketConnection.run(SVNSocketConnection.java:57)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
18:04:53    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18:04:53 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
18:04:53    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
18:04:53    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
18:04:53    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
18:04:53    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
18:04:53    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
18:04:53    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
18:04:53    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketConnection.run(SVNSocketConnection.java:57)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
18:04:53    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
18:04:53    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18:04:53 Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
18:04:53 svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/T11_2293_Digitalbanking/DevOps/EKYC-UTF8/ekycupdate'
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:702)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:113)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1035)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:164)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:480)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:833)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
18:04:53    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:133)
18:04:53 Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to check out https://hydsvnuat.icicibankltd.com/svn/T11_2293_Digitalbanking/DevOps/EKYC-UTF8/ekycupdate
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:144)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:176)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:134)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1041)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1017)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:990)
18:04:53    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1042)
18:04:53    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:937)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:864)
18:04:53    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
18:04:53    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
18:04:53    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Any ideas?

**Note**: Our Jenkins is running in a Docker container & I have recently transitioned to SVN from Git due to company policies.

Comment: What versions of the products do you use?

Answer (score -1):

To all the readers, the problem was authentication policy of our organization. Users must update their passwords every 30 days in our org.

The user must have changed the password and not updated the same in Jenkins. As a result connection was getting timed out.

The issue got resolved once the password of SVN user was updated in Jenkins as well.

Regards

Comment: I am facing this problem even I just created the svn user